How to upload a big file in chunks using js?
I have to upload multiple files to my flask server for further processing from my webpage.
Html element
<input type="file" class="file-input file-input hidden" multiple>

JavaScript Element(this is the essential js code that i think needs to be fixed.)
uploadbtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        const fileInput = dropAreaSignUp.querySelector('.file-input');
        const files = fileInput.files;

        if (files.length > 0) {
            let promises = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                promises.push(readFileData(files[i]));
            }

            Promise.all(promises)
                .then(results => {
                    const xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr1.open("POST", "/Upload_files", true);
                    xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xhr1.readyState === 4 && xhr1.status === 200) {
                            var response = JSON.parse(xhr1.responseText);
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr1.send(JSON.stringify({ files: results }));
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error reading files:", error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log('No files selected.');
        }
    });

    function readFileData(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 4 ; // 4MB chunks
            const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / CHUNK_SIZE);
            const fileChunks = [];
            let chunkIndex = 0;

            const reader = new FileReader();

            function readNextChunk() {
                const start = chunkIndex * CHUNK_SIZE;
                const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, file.size);
                console.log(start,end)
                const blob = file.slice(start, end);
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
            }

            function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
                const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                let binary = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                }
                return window.btoa(binary);
            }

            reader.onload = (event) => {
                const base64String = arrayBufferToBase64(event.target.result);
                fileChunks.push(base64String);

                chunkIndex++;
                if (chunkIndex < totalChunks) {
                    readNextChunk();
                } else {
                    resolve({
                        name: file.name,
                        size: file.size,
                        chunks: fileChunks,
                    });
                }
            };

            reader.onerror = () => {
                reject(new Error(`Error reading file ${file.name}`));
            };

            readNextChunk();
        });
    }
});

Server Side(Flask server in Python)
@app.route('/Upload_files', methods=['POST'])
def Upload_files():
    data = request.get_json()
    file_data = data['files']

    for file_info in file_data:
        file_name = file_info['name']
        file_size = file_info['size']
        file_chunks = file_info['chunks']
        print(len(file_chunks))
        joined_chunks = ''.join(file_chunks)
        with open(f'testing0.txt','w')as file:
            file.write(joined_chunks)

when i try to write it as a video file that it actually is, it gets corrupted.
Upon further investigation, i found that only the first chunk is stored properly and the rest of the chunks are not as expected. to test this u tried the following:
locally converting the video to base64 string and writing it.
import base64

with open ('static/temp/bg-video.mp4', 'rb') as file:
    data=file.read()

data= base64.b64encode(data)
with open ('testing1.txt','w')as file:
    file.write(str(data))

with open ('testing0.txt', 'r') as file:
    web_data=file.read()

with open ('testing1.txt', 'r') as file:
    manual_data=file.read()

print(len(web_data),len(manual_data))
for i in range(len(web_data)):
    if web_data[i] != manual_data[i]:
        print(web_data[i]+web_data[i+1]+web_data[i+2]+web_data[i+3]+web_data[i+4],manual_data[i]+manual_data[i+1]+manual_data[i+2]+manual_data[i+3]+manual_data[i+4],i)
        break

upon doing that i'm pretty certain that only the first chunk is being read and returned properly. rest are not working.
looking for some guidence on how can i approach or potentially solve this issue.
